# Form submission js/jquery staying on same page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to submit a form inside a CMS page and don't want a new page to load after processing the php mail script. Instead I need to display a single line success message (not an alert pop up box) without reloading the page or going to a different page.

Here's the code I have and my understanding is that the `event.preventDefault` should allow to stay on same page and `$("#contactResponse").html(data);` should put the success message on the same page.

This is my div tag above the form which is supposed to receive the success message (I've tried putting it after my form too):

```
<div id="contactResponse"></div>
```

This is my form tag:

Edit: Including my form code as well: (The div class stuff is from a custom css that someone else has done)

```
<form id="contactForm" name="contactForm" method="post" action="/myemail.php">

<div class="form-group"><input class="form-control" name="email" type="email" placeholder="Email Address" /></div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-4">
<div class="form-group"><input class="form-control" name="question" type="text" placeholder="What is your question?" /></div>
</div>
<div class="form-group"><input class="btn btn-warning btn-block" type="submit" value="Request Information"></div>
</form>
```

This is the script above my form and div tag:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $("#contactForm").submit(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        var $form = $(this),
             $submit = $form.find('button[type="submit"]'),
             email_value = $form.find('input[name="email"]').val(),
             message_value = $form.find('input[name="question"]').val(),
             url = $form.attr('action');

        var posting = $.post(url, { 
            email: email_value, 
            question: message_value 
        });

        posting.done(function(data) {
            $("#contactResponse").html(data);
        });
    });
</script>
```

The email works but the php script is on the server, and it takes me to a different page.

Can someone please give me some suggestions/advice.

Thanks

Comment: Post the full form HTML please. Are you getting any errors in the browser's console?

Comment: If the JS is above the HTML body then you need to wrap your jQuery code in a document.ready handler: `$(function() { /* your code here... */ });`. Currently your form is being submit in the standard manner, with no AJAX involved

Comment: Thanks j08691, I've added the form code
Thanks Rory, can you please tell me how to wrap, sorry I dont know

Comment: @Rory: I tried putting the JS at the bottom, i.e. after my form and section tags but its still the same :(

Comment: So from some other suggestions, I have also tried enclosing in a function like this: $(document).ready(function() {
OR
$(function(){
I closed the function right before the script tag with a " }) "
But no luck... :(

Here's what the starting looks like now:
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function(){
$("#contactForm").submit(function(event) {
.... same code as originally posted

Comment: Ok, I don't know why but the new lines are not saved in comments I guess.... I think I will have to "answer" my question if I need to provide updated code or details...

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it works for me

```
<script>
  // Get the form.
  var form = $('#contactForm');
  // Get the messages div.
  var formMessages = $('#contactResponse');
  // Set up an event listener for the contact form.
  $(form).submit(function(event) {
    // Stop the browser from submitting the form.
    event.preventDefault();
    // Serialize the form data.
    var formData = $(form).serialize();
    // Submit the form using AJAX.
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: $(form).attr('action'),
        data: formData
    }).done(function(response) {
        // Make sure that the formMessages div has the 'success' class.
        $(formMessages).removeClass('error');
        $(formMessages).addClass('success');
        // Set the message text.
        $(formMessages).text(response);
        // Clear the form.
        $('#name').val('');
        $('#email').val('');
        // $('#subject').val('');
        // $('#company').val('');
        $('#message').val('');
        $(form).hide();
    }).fail(function(data) {
        // Make sure that the formMessages div has the 'error' class.
        $(formMessages).removeClass('success');
        $(formMessages).addClass('error');
        $( "#contact" ).children(".loading").remove();
        // Set the message text.
        if (data.responseText !== '') {
            $(formMessages).text(data.responseText);
        } else {
            $(formMessages).text('Oops! An error occured and your message could not be sent.');
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks ashraf, I will try to understand it and see if it works as expected

Comment: ashraf, should I put the above code inside a SCRIPT tag or some other enclosing is also required?

Comment: yes it should be enclosed in script tag (i edited my answer), this js code should basically replace yours of the form submit handler.